# Import CSV to Python List Box Using Tkinter

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, tkinter

How would I import a CSV into a Listbox? I would like CSV data to go into the list boxes below, instead of text, is there a Python File command that would allow me to do this?

```
class RequestGUI():

    lblStatus = Label(root, text = 'Status')
    lblStatus.place(x =6, y =5)

    lblFacName = Label(root, text = 'Facility Name')
    lblFacName.place(x =150, y =5)

    lblDWGTitle = Label(root, text = 'Title')
    lblDWGTitle.place(x =525, y =5)

    colStatus = Listbox(root, height = 12, width =6)
    colStatus.place(x = 6, y = 32)
    colStatus.insert(END, " IN")

    colFacName = Listbox(root, height = 12, width =45)
    colFacName.place(x = 56, y = 32)
    colFacName.insert(END, " NW WASHINGTON")

    colDWGTitle = Listbox(root, height = 12, width =72)
    colDWGTitle.place(x = 340, y = 32)
    colDWGTitle.insert(END, " CAPACITOR VOLTAGE")
```

Comment: you will have to read the csv and insert each column into the listboxes yourself. you could however write your own function that takes the line as a tuple and adds each value to each listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk # from tkinter import * is bad, don't do this!

class RequestGUI():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.lblStatus = tk.Label(root, text = 'Status')
        self.lblStatus.place(x =6, y =5)

        self.lblFacName = tk.Label(root, text = 'Facility Name')
        self.lblFacName.place(x =150, y =5)

        self.lblDWGTitle = tk.Label(root, text = 'Title')
        self.lblDWGTitle.place(x =525, y =5)

        self.colStatus = tk.Listbox(root, height = 12, width =6)
        self.colStatus.place(x = 6, y = 32)

        self.colFacName = tk.Listbox(root, height = 12, width =45)
        self.colFacName.place(x = 56, y = 32)

        self.colDWGTitle = tk.Listbox(root, height = 12, width =72)
        self.colDWGTitle.place(x = 340, y = 32)

        self.add_row(tk.END, (" IN", " NW WASHINGTON", " CAPACITOR VOLTAGE"))

    def add_row(self, index, rowdata): # will throw indexerror if not enough data is supplied
        self.colStatus.insert(index, rowdata[0])
        self.colFacName.insert(index, rowdata[1])
        self.colDWGTitle.insert(index, rowdata[2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = tk.Tk()
    gui = RequestGUI(win)
    win.mainloop()
```

so now you have a function you can pass a tuple of the data on that rown, which will add to the listboxes. so you can simple itterate over each row in the csv file and call that function with the row data